# Moving drawings on sheet by pixels googlescripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a sheet with drawings where I move certain drawings to other cells on the page but it puts the drawing in the top left corner of the cell when I want to center it in the cell. After I move the drawing to the desired cell, I'm trying to center it by offset the drawing by # of pixels (the 1000 was a guess & check to see the # of pixels that work best).

```
dailySheet.getDrawings().forEach(d => {
const arow = d.getContainerInfo().getAnchorRow();
  if (arow in picks) {
  d.setPosition(...picks[arow].moveTo, 0, 0)
  d.setAnchorCellXOffset(1000);
```

The code above works at moving the drawing to the desired cell but the below portion of the code to offset it by # of pixels isn't working.

```
    d.setAnchorCellXOffset(1000);
```

Also please let me know if there's a better way to move drawings by pixels or centering a drawing within it's anchorcell.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this method `setAnchorCellXOffset` in the official documentation?

Comment: Appears I found my mistake but going to leave it up in case anyone else needs it.

The "0,0)" after the moveTo is the offset so change that to 1000,0) would achieve what I was trying to do and I no longer need the setAnchorCellXOffset line